# CSS style not applied when DIV populated using jQuery call

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am populating a `<DIV id='area'>` element using a PHP script and I want to repopulate the same DIV element by calling a PHP function in JavaScript if the user wishes to filter the information:

```
$("#area").load("update-dashboard.php?id=7263");
```

It populates the DIV element with the correct information but the CSS styling I'm using to format the information (eg. `class="highlight"`) doesn't get applied for some reason. So what I get *reads* correctly if I view the underlying HTML but the browser doesn't format it according to the stylesheet.

```
<style type="text/css">
.Highlight {
 background-color: #dcfac9;
 cursor: pointer;
}
td.highcell {
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
}
</style>
```

Here's what my table should contain within the DIV section:

```
<table style='border-collapse: collapse;' border=0 width='100%' id='link-table'>
<tr class='highlight'>
<td class='highcell'>
<a href="javascript:ShowWait('754', 'Car Survey', '16', 'NK51+SNR55', '', '');">NK51 SNR55</a>
</td>
<td class='highcell' width=36>
<img src='status_2.png' border=0 width=32 height=32><td class='highcell'>18-Dec-15</td>
<td class='highcell'>NK51 SNR55</td>
<td class='highcell'></td>
<td class='highcell'></td>
</tr>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
I also use this jQuery code to highlight the rows in the Table - maybe it doesn't work with HTML loaded after the page appears - if so can it be reinitialised?

```
$(function ()
{
 $('#link-table td:first-child').hide();
 $('#link-table tr').hover(function ()
 {
  $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
 });
 $('#link-table tr').click(function ()
 {
  location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
 });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your stylesheet or at least the styles you're wanting applied? CSS affects dynamic content just fine, so it is most likely something incorrect in your CSS.

Comment: Without seeing the generated code exactly it's hard to tell you what this is. It could be the following:

1. It's returning the data as encoded html, for example, `class=&quot;highlight&quot;`

2. Your style sheet isn't referenced in the document.

Comment: This is unusual. Make sure the new content is correctly formed with all necessary classes and structures. Use browser dev tools like Firebug or Chrome F12 to inspect the content before and after the replacement. There is likely a difference you missed (like a missing outer classed div).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your css from `.Highlight` to `.highlight`. CSS selectors are case-insensitive but the HTML class attributes are not.

Comment: That's not actually true. [CSS is case-**insensitive**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters); html *is* case-sensitive.

Comment: You're right.. I was just in the middle of updating!